# I want to compare 1 column in 3 CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

*Disclaimer* :
I am very new to coding and data science and this is the first project I am attempting on my own. I spent 3 hours yesterday looking through Stackoverflow but could not find a solution to my problem. I'm using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.8

I have 3 CSV files. The first is a client list(follow_up) and the other two are rosters for separate academic programs. When a client chooses either the business program(biz) or the medical program(medchem) their name and info are added to one of the two rosters(biz/medchem). When I add up the number of clients in the two roster files I see that there are about 25 clients that have not been added to either roster. I want to know who those 25 clients are.

Basically I want to look at the Student Name column in each file and return the names of the clients who have not yet chosen a program. Below is the code I have written and the result I get is a list of all the clients, not the 25 clients I'm looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

fu = pd.read_csv('follow_up.csv')
biz = pd.read_csv('biz.csv')
medchem = pd.read_csv('medchem.csv')


fu.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 4': 'Student Name'}, inplace = True)
biz.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 5': "Student Name"}, inplace = True)
medchem.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 4': "Student Name"}, inplace = True)

name_set1 = set(fu['Student Name'].values.tolist() + biz['Student Name'].values.tolist() + medchem['Student Name'].values.tolist())
fu.dropna()
biz.dropna()
medchem.dropna()

names_cleaned = set([str(name).strip().lower() for name in name_set1])
names_cleaned = set([name.strip().lower() for name in name_set1])

print(names_cleaned)
```

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: are you able to show a sample of the csv in textual format?

Comment: So you want names that are in follow_up.csv but not in biz.csv and medchem.csv, correct?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Frank: Correct

Comment: Please share samples of the CSV files. In that way more people will be able to understand your question.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the names which are not present in biz and medchem, then why are you adding them to the list instead of removing them?

There are multiple ways of achieving them. Assuming the names are identical across all the three tables.

1. Python based:

```sh
name_set1 = set(fu['Student Name'].values.tolist())
name_set2 = set(biz['Student Name'].values.tolist() + medchem['Student Name'].values.tolist())

names_missing = name_set1.difference(name_set2)
print(names_missing)
```

2. Using Pandas

```py
print(fu[~(fu['Student Name'].isin(biz['Student Name']) | fu['Student Name'].isin(biz['Student Name'])]))
```